# Item can't be moved after destination list gone empty once, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

See the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/atoDX2TqZT654dEicqeS?p=preview

How to move item from the list to the another empty list. Currently an item can't be moved once the destination list gone empty... How I can fix this for my application?

Here is the code sniped on  tags for my application:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset2" style="overflow-y:auto; height:150px;">
        <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="allDiagnosisFromDb" id="sourceList" ng-class="{'minimalList':sourceEmpty()}" class="connector">
            <li class="alert alert-danger nomargin" ng-repeat="item in allDiagnosisFromDb">{{item.Name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span4" style="overflow-y:auto; height:150px; background-color:lightgray">
        <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" id="targetList" ng-model="model" ng-class="{'minimalList':sourceEmpty()}" class="connector">
            <li class="alert alert-info nomargin" ng-repeat="item in model">{{item.Name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

code on angularjs controller:

```
    function loadAllDiagnosis() {
        $scope.allDiagnosisFromDb = [];
        diagnosisPreferanceService.getAllDiagnosis()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.allDiagnosisFromDb = data;
            })
            .error(function (xhr) {
                alert('error');
            });
    }
    // init
    $scope.model = [
        {
            "Id": 23,
            "Name": "First tem."
        }
    ];
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        connectWith: '.connector'
    }
    // watch, use 'true' to also receive updates when values
    // change, instead of just the reference
    $scope.$watch("model", function (Name) {
        console.log("Model: " + Name.map(function (e) { return e.Id }).join(','));
    }, true);
    // watch, use 'true' to also receive updates when values
    // change, instead of just the reference
    $scope.$watch("allDiagnosisFromDb", function (Name) {
        console.log("allDiagnosisFromDb: " + Name.map(function (e) { return e.Id }).join(','));
    }, true);
    $scope.sourceEmpty = function () {
        return $scope.allDiagnosisFromDb.length == 0;
    }
    $scope.modelEmpty = function () {
        return $scope.model.length == 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,,,,,,,,,:)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link exactly how you want it to be.

http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple

```
angular.module("demo").controller("SimpleDemoController", function($scope) {

  $scope.models = {
    selected: null,
    lists: {"A": [], "B": []}
  };

  // Generate initial model
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    $scope.models.lists.A.push({label: "Item A" + i});
    $scope.models.lists.B.push({label: "Item B" + i});
  }

  // Model to JSON for demo purpose
  $scope.$watch('models', function(model) {
    $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
  }, true);
});
```

Comment: I could not use this dragale UI, so I moved on my question's link, but still here is an essue: cant move items when destination list gone empty once. Please instruct me about this way, or provide me a plnkr with the http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple u provided..... thanks